# Android: Clicking Notification should stop a runing service

Tags: android, service, android-notifications

I have a service which when started makes an on-going notification in the statues bar, my intention is that when the notification is clicked, it will stop the service, and in term deletes the notification,

I just can't figure the part where clicking the notification destroys my service.

Any help here? Thanks.

Comment: are you able to get the notification ? and click on that notification one activity will call. Now you just have to stop the service while that activity is called. thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey its is very simple try

```
  notification.setItems(configFiles, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    try {
                        stopService()//put your method for stop the service
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }               
                }});
```

let me know is it helpful to you.

Comment: i am not using android 4, my app is for android 2.1, so i can't invoke a .setItems method on a notification.